# How to find labels which are assigned to each image of the validation set in the below code?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, image-classification

```
val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="validation",
  seed=121,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)
```

How to find labels which are assigned to each image of the validation set in the below code?

Answer (score 0):

`tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory()` returns a `tf.data.Dataset` object so you should be able to use the [take() method](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#take) to get dataset batches and iterate them to extract the labels. Or just iterate over the dataset:

```
for image, label in val_ds:
    print(label)
```

Answer (score 0):

vl_ds.filenames will return a list of the file names
vl.ds.labels will return a list of labels